# regular expression split in java

Tags: android, regex

I receive problem with split by regular expression in Android.
For example:

I have string: "Bin and Ban [droveǀhad driven] to London together after they [had pickedǀpicked] up the company car on Tuesday."
I want split it and expected result must be:

1. Bin and Ban
2. to London together after they
3. up the company car on Tuesday.

> String s = "Bin and Ban [droveǀhad driven] to London together after they [had pickedǀpicked] up the company car on Tuesday.";
>
> String[] array = s.split("[regular expression]");

Please help me write regular expression to split like that string, something like [*], but it's not work. Thanks.

Comment: How about `s.split("\\[[^]]\\]");`?

Comment: @ClasG Can you also help me write regular expression to get text inside [] at the same string sample ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split should be

```
        String[] array = s.split("\\s*\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*");
```

Removing of surrounding spaces wasn't requested but I assume that's what you want.

**Edit:** Removed fiddle - can't get link to work. Here's the complete code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "Bin and Ban [drove|had driven] to London together after they [had picked|picked] up the company car on Tuesday.";
        String[] array = s.split("\\s*\\[[^]]*\\]\\s*");
        System.out.println(String.join(",", array));
     }
}
```

Regards

**Edit2: As per request ;)**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "Bin and Ban [drove|had driven] to London together after they [had picked|picked] up the company car on Tuesday.";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\[([^]]*)\\]\\s*|\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\[)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while(m.find()) {
            if(m.group(2)==null)
                System.out.println("Select one: " + m.group(1));
            else
                System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
     }
}
```

This is one way (an inexperienced java coder goes about) to solve it.

Comment: Nice job. Big thank you.

Comment: Can you also help me write regular expression to get text inside [] at the same string sample ? Thanks.